# Nuxt.js can't retrieve data from Django Rest Framework API

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Nuxt.js/Vue frontend for my Django Rest Framework backend.  I can't seem to successfully load the data from my API even though I've specified permissions to allow non-authenticated users to read only.

**Index.vue**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    try {
      let customers = await $axios.$get(`/customer/`);
      return { customers };
    } catch (e) {
      return { customers: [] };
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: "Customer list"
    };
  },
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {text: 'Name', value: 'name',},
        {text: 'Address', value: 'address',},
        {text: 'City', value: 'city',},
        {text: 'Phone', value: 'phone_one',},
        {text: 'Email', value: 'email',},
      ],
      customers: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteCustomer(customer_id) {
      console.log(deleted `${customer.id}`) 
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api"
  },
}
```

I have verified that the API is working properly, but the customers array in Vue is always empty.
API is located at http://localhost:8000/api/customer to retrieve a list of customers.

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(customers)`? before to return

Comment: If you're using chrome, do `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `j` and click on network tab.   Then reload page and look for the request on the network tab.  What does it show?

Comment: @RossRogers I'm not seeing any requests bound for localhost:8000 (DRF backend), just localhost:3000 (Vue Instance)

Comment: If it isn't even sending a request to the DRF, then you need to debug why axios isn't sending it.  Also, your DRF `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` window will show a request if any reaches it, regardless of the response.

Comment: You may need to somehow set `crossDomain:true` or `xDomain: true`.

Comment: @RossRogers In Django Rest Framework I've set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing.  Does that sound like what you're talking about?

Comment: Nope.  If you don't see a request on the network tab then you haven't even sent a byte to DRF.  You need to get axios to send the request.  Then you'll need to deal with CORS stuff.  Right now, your DRF server hasn't seen  a request from your front end yet, according to your statement `"I'm not seeing any requests bound for localhost:8000 (DRF backend), just localhost:3000"`

Comment: I solved the issue, thanks a million for your help.  I'm very familiar with DRF/Django but am brand new to Nuxt/Vue, so it's certainly a learning process.  Answer posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in three places.  In both cases, syntax errors.

**First**
`return { customers};` should be `return { customers: data };`

**Second**
Remove the customers: [] declaration from the data() function.
I suppose the isn't necessary because asyncData overwrites the data anyways, but eh.  It works.

**Third**
Change `let customers = await $axios.$get(`/customer/`);` to `const data = await $axios.$get(`http://localhost:8000/api/customer/`);`

Not necessary to use the full URL but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't access to `$axios` in your `asyncData` function as [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context).

just you should to use axios as below:

```
await axios.get(`/customer/`);
```

on the other side to use `$axios.$get()` it should be [injected](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#inject-in-root-amp-context) as global context.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately my problem persists, however.  Customers is still an empty array.